# Multiple Ajax Calls calling on multiple timeouts in one page

Tags: c#, ajax, jquery

**Summery:** I have to get several data from a service(hosted on multiple servers) using C# and finally display them to the user/s, all on one page, using ajax call. Consider that the final display formats contains charts and progresses that have created by Jquery and styled by CSS.

**Some Code:**

```
// Once Called Here and Timer Will Go On
UpdateDataA();
function UpdateDataA() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {                               
            var $s = $(".second");
            $s.val(r.d[0]).trigger("change");
            updateProgressA(r.d[1]);
            updateProgressB(r.d[2]);
            updateNetworkData(bytesToSize(r.d[5], 2), bytesToSize(r.d[6], 2));
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.error);
        }

    });

    setTimeout(function () { UpdateDataA(); }, 1000);//Timer
}
```

Consider more calls like this.

**Problem:** Timer intervals doesn't update at intervals have set. One element updates correct then waits for others to complete while it shouldn't. But I need to update all continuously together. In this way, if one call crash, Others will be die.

**Question:** What can I do or What are my faults?

**Note:** I'm new to jquery and ajax.

Thank You previously

Comment: If they need to run together then why u do start the timer for dataB in dataA ?

Comment: @DarkBee It was my copy-paste fault . Edited ...

Answer (score 1):

Neglect my comment about interval. I think u will need to keep track of your timers :

`timerA = setTimeout(function () { UpdateDataA(); }, 1000);`

and clear the in the update function till task is complete

```
var timerA;

// Once Called Here and Timer Will Go On
UpdateDataA();
function UpdateDataA() {
    clearTimeout(timerA);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {                               
            var $s = $(".second");
            $s.val(r.d[0]).trigger("change");
            updateProgressA(r.d[1]);
            updateProgressB(r.d[2]);
            updateNetworkData(bytesToSize(r.d[5], 2), bytesToSize(r.d[6], 2));
            timerA = setTimeout(function () { UpdateDataA(); }, 1000);//Restart time after task is complete
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.error);
        }

    });


}
```

Comment: Nothing Chaned my friend

Comment: Well as for `if an error occurs`, u should add a [try catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647171/understanding-try-catch-in-javascript) arround the parts that can output an error. Javascript is not a multithreaded language. Meaning there will be always a small delay between the updates

Comment: Thank you indeed. Is there any other choice to update them all with less delay?

Comment: Unsure. The problem with this is that the data is fetched from a 3rd party, meaning there is no way to know/ensure that all the data will become available at the same time.